# Eclipse: import project via gradle --> failed to find target android-16

Tags: eclipse, gradle, importerror

I'm trying to import a gradle project into eclipse via gradle-plugin.
Import --> gradle project --> browsing the project. But when i hit 'Build Model' i get the error-message: "failed to find target android-16".
Android API16 is installed, reinstalling did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the SDK locations (since you said they are already installed), perhaps android studio just cant find them. Please see this link for instructions:

[Android studio - Failed to find target android-18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068920/android-studio-failed-to-find-target-android-18/24636809#24636809)

Comment: I want to import into Eclipse, not Android Studio. C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16 does exist.