# Error after importing module Volley

Tags: java, android-volley

When I`ve installed the module Volley in android studio I receive the error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':volley'.
>   failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: C:\Users\ egen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   Open Android SDK Manager

I've installed the android support repository what is wrong here?

EDIT

Now I receive the error:

Error:(10, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Fysio5'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@79554741.

This is my build.gradle:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile project(":volley")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18068920/1793718) helps. In your case its Android SDK 22 which is missing. Here's a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you don't have the Android 5.1.1 (API 22) SDK installed. Open the Android SDK manager to check and install if necessary.

Comment: I've installed that now I receive another error -_- please see my edit.

Comment: This is a new question totally unrelated to the first one. Please post a new question, don't change the original question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to app/src/build.gradle (see 1st image)
   [image]
2. Change the compileSDKVersion 22 to 19 (or to the API level that you are using)
3. Sync the project (see 2nd image)
   [image]