# Error importing from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I have installed SDK Build Tool 19.1 from SDK manager but still its giving this error While importing Eclipse Project to  Android Studio.

> Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given at [Android studio - Failed to find target android-18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068920/android-studio-failed-to-find-target-android-18) is to

- make sure that you have installed Android version 19

  > Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if Android 4.4 (API 19) is installed.

(slightly edited)

- if you have, reinstall and install it again
- alternatively, you might be able to

  > [solve[...] the problem by changing the compileSdkVersion in the Gradle.build file from 19 to 18.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18085127/1587329)